# Using a single instance of ILog in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, ninject

I'm using **Ninject** for **DI** in my **ASP.NET MVC** application. I'm resolving the `ILog` dependency in controllers using the below module

```
      public override void Load()
      {
          var configPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log4NetConfigPath"];

          // Load the external config file for Log4Net
          XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(configPath));
          log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;

          Bind<ILog>().ToMethod((c) => LogManager.GetLogger("AVLogger")).InSingletonScope();

      }
```

I'm calling the `InSingletonScope`() to provide a single instance of `ILog` instance throughout the application. I've some questions?

1. Do I need to really bother about having single instance of `ILog`? Can I remove the `InSingletonScope` method itself.
2. Does having a single instance of `ILog` create some performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how expensive it is to create your logger.  I don't know what log4net's performance characteristics are, but if it's not expensive you should just create a new one.

When you use InSingletonScope() that means the log will exist for as long as your worker process exists (ie when it's recycled or shut down, the logger will be destroyed).  That also means the logger is hanging around when you don't need it.  It's not so much of a "performance" issue, as it is one of managing resources.